# Programming Arduino's from a centralized location

Tags: arduino, ftdi

I have 16 Arduinos that are in very tight spaces and hard to get to when I need to reprogram them with my FTDI cable. I would like to have or create some sort of centralized place where I can connect my FTDI cable, make some sort of selection (switch of some sort), which will then connect the pins my cable is on to the selected arduino.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?  I've toyed with transistors, but that takes a lot of them and didn't quite work.

Are there any premade solutions that are out there that I have yet to find?

Thanks very much!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware design. Ask on [electronics.se]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought! TCP to Serial.

Sound complicated.

Not really.

Note from AVRDUDE's manual the following

> For programmers that attach to a serial port using some kind of higher
>   level protocol (as opposed to bit-bang style programmers), port can be
>   specified as net:host:port. In this case, instead of trying to open a
>   local device, a TCP network connection to (TCP) port on host is
>   established. The remote endpoint is assumed to be a terminal or
>   console server that connects the network stream to a local serial port
>   where the actual programmer has been attached to. The port is assumed
>   to be properly configured, for example using a transparent 8-bit data
>   connection without parity at 115200 Baud for a STK500.

With this, One could place your Arduino's behind your choice of TCP to Serial Server. Which is available in several forms. Cisco has a gang TS (but that is expensive, unless used). lantronix (and others have single end point devices. But then for Linux, there is "Net2Ser" which can serve up all your ttyS (aka Serial/COM ports).

With the later you could use a raspberry or TP-Link TL-WR703N (

---

In the latest IDE 1.5.6r2 add one entry for each TCP-to-Serial Port to ./Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/programmers.txt file. While replacing the IP and Port with corresponding values.

```
TCP2001.name=TCP 2001
TCP2001.communication=serial
TCP2001.protocol=stk500v1
TCP2001.program.protocol=stk500v1
TCP2001.program.tool=avrdude
TCP2001.program.extra_params=-Pnet:192.168.1.100:2001

TCP2002.name=TCP 2002
TCP2002.communication=serial
TCP2002.protocol=stk500v1
TCP2002.program.protocol=stk500v1
TCP2002.program.tool=avrdude
TCP2002.program.extra_params=-Pnet:192.168.1.100:2002

...
```

Additionally change "protocol" to "upload.protocol" the following line in ./Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt

```
tools.avrdude.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {program.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i"
```

to

```
tools.avrdude.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {program.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{upload.protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i"
```

With this you can use "Upload Using Programmer" with the selected programmer to send over TCP, rather then use the Upload.

---

That all said, it will only work on Linux.

> avrdude: ser_open(): network connects are currently notimplemented for Win32 environments